# PHP: File upload won't work

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm having trouble making file uploads with my PHP code. I've checked out a few tutorials and some debug tips and advice (on here and off here), but nothing is working. print_r($_FILES) yields no results. Here's my HTML code:

```
<form action="admin_avatars.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Image: <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" /></p>
    <p class="buttonset"><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

And here's my PHP code (with an ini_get just to make sure my file_uploads is set to "on"):

```
print("[ini get: ".ini_get("file_uploads")."]<br />");
print("[".$_FILES["avatar"]["name"]. "==".$_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"]."]<br />");
```

And, for this, I get the output:

```
[ini get: 1]
[==]
```

Kinda stumped at this point why nothing is uploading or why $_FILES isn't being filled with anything. What small detail am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing here which would upload a file. Have you read the [how-to](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)?

Comment: How big is the file? check your `post_max_size`

Comment: @JayBlanchard, in what way is there nothing there to upload a file? There's a form with method="post" and enctype="multipart/form-data", an input with "file" type, and a submit button. Then there's a print statement to get some $_FILES settings. Not sure what I'm missing.
Edit: yes, I realize I'm not "doing" anything with the file. But I'm not even at that stage. If the file was successfully uploaded, there should at least be a $_FILES["avatar"]["name"] or ["tmp_name"] value.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, good call. I just checked and my max_file_size is set to 8M, the image I'm testing is 172KB.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, whoops. Sorry. Said max_file_size, meant post_max_size. It's 8M. My bad.

Comment: I did have a search for some edge cases which may be the issue, the code you provided should work. If you have not change any `php.ini` values and put in the wrong values like `MB` instead of `M` it should work. Maybe dump out `<?php phpinfo() ?>` and see if something looks weird, does normal `$_POST` values come through?

Comment: Out of curiosity you're not posting this with ajax are you?

Comment: Also try just `print_r($_FILES)`, you might have a typo or something..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for some reason it suddenly works. And I'm not sure why. All the elements that I can see remain the same, but here's my PHP code (PHP is the only thing I changed):

```
if($_FILES["character_image"]["name"] <> "") {
    $newfilename = $directory_characters . "/" . createfilename($_REQUEST["character_name"]) . "." . pathinfo($_FILES["character_image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $imagesizeinformation = getimagesize($_FILES["character_image"]["tmp_name"]);
    copy($_FILES["character_image"]["tmp_name"], $newfilename);
}
```

Just in case, here's my HTML code at its barest:

```
<form action="admin_characters.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Image: <input type="file" name="character_image" id="character_image" />
    <p class="buttonset"><input type="submit" value="Add" /></p>
</form>
```

If anybody knows what fixed my problem, please let everyone know. I'm stumped what happened here that suddenly allowed the images to come through.